# How to Open Java Swing UI in intelliJ?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I just imported a Java Project that has several UI files which have the extension .java with them. All of them use Java Swing. However, when I open the code on IntelliJ, it only shows me the code base. I want to see the UI Form, how to achieve this?

Comment: What if you run the app?

Comment: I can run the app, and everything works fine. But is there a way to specifically see the UI of a particular Frame alone?

Comment: you mean you need a plugin for a wysiwyg editor in intellij?

Comment: https://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/

Comment: @Stultuske yes, Something like the editor tab in Eclipse

Comment: rephrasing: I have a java Class, which uses Java Swing . I want to see the output of this class / of this GUI alone

Comment: Code designed in one IDE's (drag & drop) GUI editor are typically not compatible with any other GUI editor. Code written without a GUI designer is not importable into any GUI designer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the default GUI designer that comes with Intellij IDEA cannot parse and display pure java code. It requires an extra `.form` file. However Eclipse [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) parses pure java code.